# Definition of continuously differentiable for functions of several variables

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

When we say that a function $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is $C^1$, what exactly does this mean?  Does it mean that all the directional derivatives are continuous individually (I am sure not), or that the derivative $D_uf(\vec{x})$ is continuous as a function of both $\vec{x}$ **and** $u$ (thus viewing $D_\cdot f(\cdot)$ as acting on $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$)?

Or is here some more robust notion I should be thinking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does mean that all directional derivatives are continuous individually. This is equivalent to saying that $Df(x)u$ is continuous as a function of both $x$ and $u$. It is also equivalent to the more easily checked statement that for each $i$ and $j$, $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}$ is continuous.